# Select Distinct month and year from mysql timestamp field and echo them in php

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql table has a createdOn column with filedtype 'timestamp' in the format of `2011-10-13 14:11:12`.

What I need is to show, is distinct month,year from createdOn column.

I have searched on stackover flow and was able to echo back months using following code,

```
*$sqlCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(createdOn) AS 'Month' FROM videoBase ORDER BY createdOn DESC";
$query=mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $date = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['Month']));
    echo ''.$date.' <br />';
}*
```

This outputs months as :

```
October
January
```

What I need is the output in the format of:

```
October 2011
January 2012
```

Can anybody please let me know, what changes I should make in the code in order to get the required output.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the replies. just been able to solve the issue. I have used the mysql query as suggested by Marcus and then used EscoMaji $date = date("F, Y", strtotime($row['Month']));
It gives me output in the form of October 2011, February 2012 and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$date = date("F Y", strtotime($row['Month']));
```

and in your query don't select the month, just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT createdOn AS 'Month' FROM videoBase ...
```

So it will be:

```
$comma = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $date = $comma . date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['Month']));
    echo $comma . $date;
    $comma = ', ';
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried this and it has given the following output:         October 2011 
February 2012 
February 2012 
February 2012   which is due to the fact that every timestamp is Distnct. While I need the outpu as October 2011, February 2012, March 2012. Just distinct month with year.

Answer (score 10):

For a MySQL solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(createdOn), ' ', YEAR(createdOn)) AS `Month`
FROM videoBase
ORDER BY createdOn DESC
```

This takes the output of the `MONTHNAME()` function and `YEAR()` function and concatenates them with a space between, like this:

```
October 2011
January 2012
```

Answer (score -1):

try below for current year

```
 echo $date.date("Y");
```

OR if you want specific year then you must have to take from database table

Thanks

Comment: I have just append the current year at the end of the month name above code is same from the question

Comment: this still won't work, the DATE will get the current year, not the one from the query.

Comment: see my comment on answer "OR if you want specific year then you must have to take from database table"